# How to get text between two strings with special characters in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, xpath

I have a string (@description) that contains HTML code and I want to extract the content between two elements. It looks something like this

```
<b>Content title<b><br/>
*All the content I want to extract*
<a href="javascript:print()">
```

I've managed to do something like this

```
@want = @description.match(/Content title(.*?)javascript:print()/m)[1].strip
```

But obviously this solution is far from perfect as I get some unwanted characters in my @want string.

Thanks for your help

Edit:

As requested in the comments, here is the full code:

I'm already parsing an HTML document doing something where the following code:

```
@description = @doc.at_css(".entry-content").to_s
puts @description
```

returns:

```
<div class="post-body entry-content">
<a href="http://www.photourl"><img alt="Photo title" height="333"     src="http://photourl.com" width="500"></a><br><br><div style="text-align: justify;">
Some text</div>
<b>More text</b><br><b>More text</b><br><br><ul>
<li>Numered item</li>
<li>Numered item</li>
<li>Numered item</li>
</ul>
<br><b>Content Title</b><br>
Some text<br><br>
Some text(with links and images)<br>
Some text(with links and images)<br>
Some text(with links and images)<br>
<br><br><a href="javascript:print()"><img src="http://url.com/photo.jpg"></a>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

The text can include more paragraphs, links, images, etc. but it always starts with the "Content Title" part and ends with the javascript reference.

Comment: Sounds like **Xpath** will be cleaner than regex there.

Comment: Any particular reason that you want to use a regex when there are HTML parsers available?

Comment: Not really, but I couldn't find a way to do it with Xpath either

Comment: Don't try to parse HTML with a regex, it's generally a bad idea: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: @Lemurido, Consider pasting more html code, we will help you with Xpath or any parser.

Comment: Thanks @sputnick, I've added more HTML code as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XPath expression selects all (sibling) nodes between the nodes `$vStart` and `$vEnd`:**

```
  $vStart/following-sibling::node()
           [count(.|$vEnd/preceding-sibling::node())
           =
            count($vEnd/preceding-sibling::node())
           ]
```

To obtain the full XPath expression to use in your specific case, simply substitute `$vStart` with:

```
/*/b[. = 'Content Title']
```

and substitute `$vEnd` with:

```
/*/a[@href = 'javascript:print()']
```

The final XPath expressions after the substitutions is:

```
/*/b[. = 'Content Title']/following-sibling::node()
         [count(.|/*/a[@href = 'javascript:print()']/preceding-sibling::node())
         =
          count(/*/a[@href = 'javascript:print()']/preceding-sibling::node())
         ]
```

**Explanation**:

This is a simple corollary of the Kayessian formula for the intersection of two nodesets `$ns1` and `$ns2`:

```
$ns1[count(.|$ns2) = count($ns2)]
```

In our case, the set of all nodes between the nodes `$vStart` and `$vEnd` is the intersection of two node-sets: all following siblings of `$vStart` and all preceding siblings of `$vEnd`.

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vStart" select="/*/b[. = 'Content Title']"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vEnd" select="/*/a[@href = 'javascript:print()']"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "$vStart/following-sibling::node()
               [count(.|$vEnd/preceding-sibling::node())
               =
                count($vEnd/preceding-sibling::node())
               ]
     "/>
==============

     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "/*/b[. = 'Content Title']/following-sibling::node()
               [count(.|/*/a[@href = 'javascript:print()']/preceding-sibling::node())
               =
                count(/*/a[@href = 'javascript:print()']/preceding-sibling::node())
               ]
     "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (converted to a well-formed XML document):

```
<div class="post-body entry-content">
    <a href="http://www.photourl">
        <img alt="Photo title" height="333"     src="http://photourl.com" width="500"/>
    </a>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div style="text-align: justify;">
    Some text</div>
    <b>More text</b>
    <br />
    <b>More text</b>
    <br />
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li>Numered item</li>
        <li>Numered item</li>
        <li>Numered item</li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    <b>Content Title</b>
    <br />
    Some text
    <br />
    <br />
    Some text(with links and images)
    <br />
    Some text(with links and images)
    <br />
    Some text(with links and images)
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <a href="javascript:print()">
        <img src="http://url.com/photo.jpg"/>
    </a>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

**the two XPath expressions (with and without variable references) are evaluated and the nodes selected in each case, conveniently delimited, are copied to the output**:

```
<br/>
    Some text
    <br/>
<br/>
    Some text(with links and images)
    <br/>
    Some text(with links and images)
    <br/>
    Some text(with links and images)
    <br/>
<br/>
<br/>
==============

     <br/>
    Some text
    <br/>
<br/>
    Some text(with links and images)
    <br/>
    Some text(with links and images)
    <br/>
    Some text(with links and images)
    <br/>
<br/>
<br/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to make this work with Nokogiri and it isn't returning anything. For example, trying to crawl       
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://mashable.com/2012/10/01/ipad-mini-less-of-everything/')) and then
description = doc.xpath("/*/h2[. = 'Less = More']/following-sibling::node()
         [count(.|/*/h2[. = 'A Nice Museum']/preceding-sibling::node())
         =
          count(/*/h2[. = 'A Nice Museum']/preceding-sibling::node())
         ]")
puts description
Doesn't return anything. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Lemurido, Any compliant XPath 1.0 processor must evaluate this expression and select the same nodes. Either the one used by Nokogiri is incompliant/buggy, or, more likely, you have a copy/paste or other kind of error -- in the code that we haven't been shown.

Answer (score 0):

To test your HTML, I have added tags around your code then pasting it in a [file](http://pastie.org/4889265)

```
xmllint --html --xpath '/html/body/div/text()' /tmp/l.html
```

output :

```
Some text
Some text
Some text
Some text
```

Now, you can use an Xpath module in `ruby` and re-use the Xpath expression

You will find many examples on stackoverflow website searches.

Comment: If you think that the answer is useful, you can 'upvote' it. You can 'accept' the reply too by clicking the `checkmark` (will be green), this way, people searching stackoverflow website will known that the question is well answered. That's how stackoverflow works, thanks ;)